# How to run two different events with separated PostBacks on Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have Button with code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Label1.Text = "Searching for services";
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
```

but in addition I need to show something when I will find my services so I add another event:

```
    Button1.Click += (s, k) => {
        discovery.FindAlreadyRegisteredServices();
        discovery.discoveryClient.FindCompleted += FoundEvent;
        auto[1].WaitOne();
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    };
```

which is slow (and controlled by AutoResetEvent)

```
protected void FoundEvent(object sender, FindCompletedEventArgs e) {
    Label1.Text = "Found " + ((discovery.endpoints.Count > 0) ? discovery.endpoints[0].Address.ToString() : "nothing");
    auto[1].Set();
}
```

The problem is that my `Button1.Click += (s, k) =>` just makes no sense at all because it executes after `Button1_Click` and there is no `PostBack` until all the bonded events will be finished?

I know that I can use everything I want right on client by using `UpdateProgress` and `javascript` but what I want here is client to sent 2 events and wait for 2 answers, make 2 PostBacks. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that I can use everything I want right on client by using UpdateProgress and javascript but what I want here is client to sent 2 events and wait for 2 answers, make 2 PostBacks.

Why? It seems like an arbitrary constraint that's making an otherwise trivial task unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Label1.Text = "Searching for services";
    //change postback hooks
    Button1.Click -= Button1_Click;
    Button1.Click += AnotherEventPB;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStarupScript(this, GetType(), postback, "__doPostBack();", true);
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}

protected void AnotherEventPB(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //reset postback hooks
        Button1.Click -= AnotherEventPB; 
        Button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        discovery.FindAlreadyRegisteredServices();
        discovery.discoveryClient.FindCompleted += FoundEvent;
        auto[1].WaitOne();
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Comment: `postback` should be string in `RegisterStarupScript`, and seems like it doesn't execute `AnotherEventPB`. May you explain when it must come to `AnotherEventPB`?

Comment: @Heather, What I am doing is trying to call AnotherEventPB after one postback has finished executing.

Comment: I guess RegisterStarupScript should make button to Click second time?